# Overridden View Error recursion

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view

I have BaseController :

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
        {
            return View(viewName, model);
        }
    }
```

I'll change this View logic in the future. And I have another Controller:

```
public partial class BrandController : BaseController
    {    
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {

            return base.View(Views.Index,"", new Model()
            {      

            );
        }
```

I'm just trying to call overridden method in my BaseController and BaseController should return View(). But I've got recursion error in overridden View() method.

Answer (score 0):

When `Index()` gets called, it calls `View(...)` from the base class. This method returns a value that is calculated by calling `View(...)`, which returns a value that is calculated by calling `View(...)`, which returns a value that is calculated by calling `View(...)`, which returns a value that is calculated by calling `View(...)` ...

Comment: I know it. But I need some solution and explanation why is it so))

Comment: @Andjey because you told it to do so. The code that gets executed when `View(...)` is called basically just says "Call me again". So it gets called again and executes the same code, which says "Call me again". If `View(...)` should return a new object of type `ViewResult`, try `return new ViewResult()`.

Comment: But I need to pass parameters.

Comment: @Andjey If you need to pass parameters to the constructor of ViewResult, then do so. `return new ViewResult(/*insert your parameters here*/);`

Comment: Check, please, ViewResult type doesn't have any param constructors.

Comment: @Andjey give detailed information, please. Where do you want to pass parameters? To `View(...)`? Just call it with parameters `base.View(Views.Index,"", new Model());`. But don't call `View(...)` inside `View(...)` if you have no reason for recursion and especially not if you don't have a termination condition.